# KL Divergence between the solution to two SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

What is the KL divergence between the laws of solutions to SDEs? That is, let

\begin{align*}
dX^1&=b_1(X^1,t) \, dt+\sigma(X^1,t) \, dB\\
dX^2&=b_2(X^2,t) \, dt+\sigma(X^2,t) \, dB
\end{align*}

Let the laws of $X^1$ and $X^2$ be denoted by $\mu^1, \mu^2$ respectively. What is

$$E_{\mu^1}\left[\log\left(\frac{d\mu^1}{d\mu^2}\right)\right]?$$

I know that

$$E_{\mu^1}\left[\log\left(\frac{d\mu^1}{d\mu^2}\right)\right]=E_{\mu^1}\left[\int_0^T \frac{b_1(X^2(t),t)-b_1(X^2(t),t)}{\sigma(X^2(t),t)} \, dB(t)-\frac12\int_0^T\left(\frac{b_1(X^2(t),t)-b_1(X^2(t),t)}{\sigma(X^2(t),t)}\right)^2 \, dt\right].$$

I know that if $\sigma$ is constant and $b_2=0$ then

$$E_{\mu^1}\left[\log\left(\frac{d\mu^1}{d\mu^2}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} E_{\mu^1} \left[\int_0^T b_1^2(\omega(t),t) \, dt\right]$$

where $\omega$ is a generic path. What if $\sigma$ is more general and $b_2$ is not $0$?

Comment: what type of answer do you expect? The one from Girsanov seems as good as one get for such general coefficients.

Comment: @ThomasKojar An expression without any Ito integrals